# Future subjunctive vs future indicative vs conditional

Tags: subjuntivo, condicional, indicativa

How do I say
'If he chats with me again, I will be more restrained.'

1. Si él charle conmigo de nuevo, seré distante.
2. Si él charle conmigo de nuevo, seria distante.
3. Si él charle conmigo de nuevo, fuere distante.
4. Si él charlare conmigo de nuevo, fuere distante.

etc

What is the combination here?
subjunctive + indicative or
subjunctive + conditional
etc.

Comment: Are you refering to a chat like facebook or whatsapp, or a simple conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use future subjunctive here (recall it's not used in anything but the most formal of documents), then the pattern is *Si **fut. subj.**, **fut. ind.***. In your example

> Si él charlare conmigo de nuevo, seré distante.

That usage is pretty much entirely extinct in Spanish, though it is preserved in Portuguese: *Se ele **conversar** comigo de novo, **serei** distante*

Future subjunctive, in the rare case that it's used in Modern Spanish, tends to be limited to relative clauses where it can be contrasted with present subject:

- Seré distante hacia el *que me **intentare** conversar*
  <sup>(… to whomever tries to converse with me; it's possible that *no one* will try)</sup>
- Seré distante hacia el *que me **intente** conversar*
  <sup>(… to whomever tries to converse with me; *someone* will try, I just don't know who)</sup>

Comment: Ok, so what is the contemporary usage like? As rsanchez says,  present indicative + future indicative or future indicative + future indicative.

Comment: @AsharaDayne that's exactly correct for contemporary usage of those phrases — future subjunctive simply isn't used. The only time you might hear future subjunctive outside of set phrases would be in something like "Hablaré con la persona que fuere presidente" (I will speak with whomever in down the road be the president) vs "Hablaré con la persona que sea el presidente" (I will speak with whomever is currently the president). You'll only see it in legal texts though and maybe a poem once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You use present indicative + future indicative:

> Si charla conmigo de nuevo, seré distante.